# ng2-pdfjs-viewer left sidebar behaviour

Tags: ng2-pdfjs-viewer

The left sidebar seems to be closed by default for few pdfs and opened for few others? Is the tool taking some kind of decision on how it should be?

I had tried to close the sidebar always using the onDocumentLoad event, but the problem is, the side bar appears for a split second before being closed programmatically. Causing a flicker.

```
loadComplete() {
   this.pdfViewer.PDFViewerApplication.pdfSidebar.close(); //close the left nav
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution.

Instead of depending on the onDocumentLoad i tried the following and it worked.

```
<ng2-pdfjs-viewer
  ...
  pagemode="none"
></ng2-pdfjs-viewer>
```

Turned out to be quite straightforward in the end and it is mentioned in the document as well.

`pagemode` - *State of sidebar. Available options are none, thumbs,bookmarks,attachments. E.g. pagemode=attachments.*

From the documentation, i got the idea that if i use `pagemode="none"` the left side bar would not appear at all. `pagemode="closed"` would have made it instantly understandable :)